# Date-Selection only when date is selected

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I'm using ngx-bootstrap and follow different implementation suggestions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43650171/how-to-add-pop-up-date-pickar-using-ngx-bootstrap) or solutions proposed in [here](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/273). If I use it like

```
<div class="input-group-addon datepickerCLS" dropdown (click)="toggleCalendar($event)"
      (clickOutside)="closeCalendar($event)" [isOpen]="showCal">
<button dropdownToggle type="button" class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar datepickerCLS" aria-hidden="true">
</button>
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" >
 <datepicker [(ngModel)]="internalDate" 
             [startingDay]="startD" [showWeeks]="true" 
             (selectionDone)="setDate()">
 </datepicker>
</div>
</div>
```

than I get notifications when the user change the date by

1. Day selection
2. Month selection
3. Year selection

to distinguish between a day-selection and a month or weekselection. I'm aware that I can add something like

```
(click)="checkPath($event)"
```

and evaluate `event.path()` if it contains either `daypicker, monthpicker or yearpicker`. But this approach works *only* in Chrome, not in FF.

Is there a way to distinguish in caught events if this is either in the day selection or in some other selections?

Comment: I found as well the `ngx-bootstrap/datepicker2  bsDatePickerPopup` but do not know how to use it right now - although the version 2.0.0beta3 is installed.... Hints would be appreciated...